# append currency symbol to result of sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The result of a sql query

```
select PayerDate,PaymentAmount from Payments
```

PaymentAmount - decimal

```
Date        Amount
12/11/2012  34.31
12/11/2012  95.60
12/11/2012  34.31
```

is that possible to get the result of query as below:

```
Date        Amount
12/11/2012  $34.31
12/11/2012  $95.60
12/11/2012  $34.31
```

I have tried but couldn't find much info on this.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Why not just concatenate a $ before the number cast as `varchar`?

Comment: @JW웃 SQL Server 2008, and PaymentAmount is decimal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can concatenate it on your projection statement,

In MySQL,

```
SELECT PayerDate, CONCAT('$', PaymentAmount) PaymentAmount
FROM Payments
```

In SQL Server,

```
SELECT PayerDate, '$' + CAST(PaymentAmount AS VARCHAR(15)) PaymentAmount
FROM   Payments
```

Comment: Sorry to ask this. Is that possible with out casting? as i need to change datatypes in my classes

Comment: you need to cast it because you are concatenating a string into a decimal data type. If you are working on it on the application level, you can add extra column which is not processed, ex. `SELECT PayerDate, '$' + CAST(PaymentAmount AS VARCHAR(15)) StrPaymentAmount, PaymentAmount
FROM   Payments`. For presentation use `StrPaymentAmount` and for calculation use `PaymentAmount`. how about that?

Comment: Can also please tell, how to control the decimal places after casting to string? For example it is returning value like "$352.4500", i want like "$352.45". If it is decimal value i can control it on my Reports but not strings.

Comment: OMG. SQL Fiddle. I will start using this. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnWoo I get `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.` when doing this?

Comment: nm...I needed to allocate more memory to varchar

Answer (score 3):

Try this Query

```
select PayerDate,'$'+convert(varchar,PaymentAmount) as PaymentAmount
from Payments
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `PaymentAmount` to a string, and prefix it with a dollar:

```
select  PayerDate
,       '$' + cast(PaymentAmount as varchar(20)) as PaymentAmount
from    Payments
```

Answer (score 0):

John Woo sql server answer is right but you might get an error like " "$" is not a valid column name". To prevent this error do some housing keeping by adding parenthesis.

```
SELECT PayerDate, ('$' + CAST(PaymentAmount AS VARCHAR(15))) AS PaymentAmount
FROM   Payments
```

Note: I only added parenthesis.

Answer (score -1):

The following can be tried:

```
SELECT 
FORMAT([PayerDate], 'C' 'en-us') AS PayerDate ,
FORMAT([PaymentAmount], 'C', 'en-us') AS 'PaymentAmount' 
FROM Payments
```