# Show the number in the form of currency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have numbers like `275,10801,276028`

I need to show them in the following form as currency like `$275,$10,801,$2,76,028` .Can someone tell me how should I do that in a sql server view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append currency symbol to result of sql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433455/append-currency-symbol-to-result-of-sql-query)

Comment: You should leave the formatting to the front end.

Comment: But how do I get the , symbol between the numbers like 10,801 and 2,76,028 .

Comment: Are you asking how to insert currency symbols, e.g. `$`, and thousands separators (`,`) into a comma separated _list_ of numeric values exactly as you have shown? Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: It's not a good idea to append $ in VIEW. It's a sort killer ($9>$10)! Let VIEW consumers decide. If you are absolutely sure, I would prefer `SELECT FORMAT(Val, '$#,#') FROM (VALUES (275),(10801),(276028)) T(Val)`

Answer (score 4):

`Please try below code once
SELECT FORMAT(275, 'C', 'en-us')  Output: $275.00
SELECT FORMAT(275, 'C0', 'en-us') Output: $275`

Answer (score 2):

Use Format function

```
SELECT FORMAT(275, 'C', 'en-us')
```

Comment: I am getting the numbers in following format like 275.00, 10,812.00,2,78,000.00 but I don't want the values after the decimal or after them I just want to display 10,812

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select '$'+cast(your_value as nvarchar) from your_table
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the desired format in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Without decimal
select left(ltrim(convert(varchar, cast(12345678.89 as money),1)), charindex('.',ltrim(convert(varchar, cast(12345678.89 as money),1)))-1)

or for any version of SQL Server for 2012 and above:

```
select format(123456.78 ,'#,#')
```