# Add symbol to Row values of select query output

Tags: sql-server

I have transposed results of a select query through PIVOT to get the results as shown below. All the values are in decimal(18,1) format.

```
          || Item1 || Item2 || Item3
Avg_Price ||  234  ||  156  ||   73
%share    ||   17  ||   3   ||   35
```

I need to add $ and % symbols to th rows Avg_Price and %share, respectively. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Giving the PIVOT query here, as requested by @B3S.

```
select [Name],  [Item1],[Item2],[Item3],[Total]
from
  (
  select [Item_Type], [Name], value
  from (select [Item_Type],[Total Sales],[Share of Total Sales],[Average Price],[$0 to $99],[$100 to $199],[$200+]
    from    (SELECT [Item_Type],[Total Sales],CAST([Total Sales]*100.0/(SELECT SUM([Total Sales]) FROM My_DB.dbo.Sales_Data GROUP BY [Year],[Month]) AS DECIMAL(38,1)) [Share of Total Sales],[Average Price],[$0 to $99],[$100 to $199],[$200+] 
            FROM My_DB.dbo.Sales_Data
            union all
            select 'Total',SUM([Total Sales]),SUM([Total Sales])*100.0/(SELECT SUM([Total Sales]) FROM My_DB.dbo.Sales_Data GROUP BY [Year],[Month]) [Share of Total Sales],CAST(AVG([Average Price]) AS DECIMAL(38,1)),SUM([$0 to $99]),SUM([$100 to $199]),SUM([$200+])
            from My_DB.dbo.Sales_Data
            GROUP BY [Year],[Month]) d
    ) e
  unpivot
  (
    value for [Name] in ([Total Sales],[Share of Total Sales],[Average Price],[$0 to $99],[$100 to $199],[$200+])
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for [Item_Type] in ( [Item1],[Item2],[Item3],[Total])
) piv;
```

EDIT: It is not a duplicate question. It is a different question to the one being pointed here. I had posted this question to seek an efficient way of updating values in a row instead of querying every single value and appending it.

Comment: provide your query please

Comment: Formatting does not belong in the database, you do that sort of thing in the front end.

Comment: @SeanLange, I totally appreciate it. The reason, I am seeking to achieve this within SQL Output is that the system, where I need to use this data, does not allow to add symbols to Row Values.

Comment: Well if it allows things like sorting you have other fun challenges to work with. And what kind of front end doesn't allow formatting of data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append currency symbol to result of sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16433455/append-currency-symbol-to-result-of-sql-query)

Comment: @SeanLange a store-bought one that you can't modify.

Comment: @TabAlleman, the question you are referring to is for appending symbol to a column. Whereas, I am seeking a way to append symbol to all the values in a ROW.

Comment: @RAVIBANSAL yes but if you append in the derived table, where you are getting `Total Sales` and `% share`, the technique is the same.

Comment: I understand that solution is similar to the duplicate question you are pointing me to but on what basis have you downgraded my question? Hope, you are feeling better now. Get well soon.

Comment: I have had already checked out those questions. I had posted this question of mine seeking a more efficient way to update row values instead of querying each individual value and appending the symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `[Item1]` etc. with some string manipulation.

```
declare @i int = 1
select '$' + convert(varchar, @i * 1.00)
select convert(varchar, @i) + '%'
```

You may need something like:

```
SELECT [Name], 
CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Avg_Price' THEN '$' + convert(varchar, [Item1] * 1.00) 
ELSE convert(varchar, [Item1]) + '%'
END AS [Item1],
CASE WHEN [Name] = 'Avg_Price' THEN '$' + convert(varchar, [Item2] * 1.00) 
ELSE convert(varchar, [Item2]) + '%'
END AS [Item2],
... etc...
```